# API returns error: Request for principal permission failed

Tags: c#, xml, api, soap, postman

I am consuming another company's SOAP API via postman and it keeps returning an error

Based on my research, when people have been getting this error, they are also developing the API and the fix was always a server-side edit. So, I am lead to believe that this error is not my fault.

I can get other errors if I use incorrect credentials, bad XML formatting, etc. I can successfully use the SOAP "Login" request for this API, but the all the getter SOAP requests for this API throw this same error

I don't believe this is an account permission error because my I was told by my superiors the account had the permissions required. Is there something I can do on my end to resolve this error?

My SOAP Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://url/omitted/">
            <userName>{{username}}</userName>
            <userPassword>{{password}}</userPassword>
        </AuthenticationHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetDeviceCommands xmlns="http://url/omitted/">
            <datagateId>{{datagateid}}</datagateId>
        </GetDeviceCommands>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The Error:

```
<soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Request for principal permission failed.</faultstring>
    <detail />
</soap:Fault>
```

I get the same error when I make the request from a c# as well, so I know it is server-side.

```
System.AggregateException: 'constructorArgs[0]Server was unable to process
request. ---> Request for principal permission failed.)'

Inner Exception
FaultException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Request for principal permission failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a permission error, whoever set up the account did it incorrectly.